# How to print a RandomAccessFile to a .txt file while scanning for spaces and inserting extra spaces after each one

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a binary data reader that reads a .dat file to "output.txt", but while it is copying the file, it should check for spaces. When it finds a space, I set it up so that it would automatically print a space to the file, then continue copying the file. However, it does not do anything. Here is my code:

```
/*
binReader.java

Justin Wang
*/

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class binReader {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final String customHeader = "STATE POP CHILD POVERTYCHILD % POVERTY";
        final String customSubHeader = "______________________________________";

        try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
                RandomAccessFile binData = new RandomAccessFile("binaryFile.dat", "rw");) {
            output.println(customHeader);
            output.println(customSubHeader);

            for (int i = 0; i < binData.length(); i += 2) {
                binData.seek(i); // sets the pointer

                if (Character.toString(binData.readChar()) == " ") {
                    output.print("     ");
                    } //adds an extra space where other spaces have been
                binData.seek(i);
                output.print(binData.readChar());
            } // reads the entire file

        } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't compare strings with ==. And why do you think you need a RandomAccessFile here?

Comment: So I use the .equals() instead? Also: I just learned how to use them, I might as well.

Comment: Yes, you should always use `equals()` to compare strings. And for your cuse case a simple [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) would be sufficient.